# Edit a record from a DB table using EJB3?

Tags: ejb-3.0

im quite new to EJB3 and was wondering if it is possible to edit a specific record from a table using EJB3?

If so, are there any tutorials and examples on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since entity beans were deprecated in the EJB3 standatd, you'd do this using either plain JDBC or JPA, but neither of these requires EJBs to be used.

Comment: Indeed, EJB does not do persistence directly and you'd use JDBC or JPA for this. However, EJB does make it a whole lot easier and straightforward to use JPA.